# Print Unicode with write

Tags: c, unicode

I don't understand why my Unicode character doesn't display to the screen.  I'm recoding the `printf` function (to learn)..

```
static void     print_unicode(wchar_t c)
{
    write(1, &c, 4);
}

int     c_format(va_list *v1, char *options, char format)
{
    char        c;
    wchar_t     uc;
    int     count;
    t_bool  unicode;

    uc = 0;
    unicode = check_flags(options, "l");
    if (format == '%')
        c = '%';
    else if (unicode)
        uc = (wchar_t)va_arg(*v1, unsigned int);
    else
        c = (char)va_arg(*v1, int);
    count = 1;
    display_padding(options, &count, 1);
    if (unicode)
        print_unicode(uc);
    else        
        ft_putchar(c);
    display_padding(options, &count, 0);
    return (count);
}
```

The Unicode character on the stack is `wchar_t nb1 = L'ሴ';` The environment is Linux.

Comment: What (if any) output do you get?

Comment: This could very well be endianness-related, printing the bytes of a multibyte integer like that is ... fragile.

Comment: In my view, the most likely problem is that your terminal interprets UTF-8 yet you're writing (UTF-16 or) UTF-32.  The character you show, ሴ, appears to be U+1234 (with UTF-8 representation 0xE1 0x88 0xB4), which is from the Ethiopic script.

Comment: It would help if you added a small `main()` program so that we can see how you're relaying the `va_list *` to your function (there's probably an intermediate function with ellipsis `...` in the function signature).  It is more normal to use `va_list`, but there could be mitigating circumstances.  Please review how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: @ChrisTurner I get "4"

Comment: The `4` is consistent with the bytes found in the UTF-32 representation of U+1234.  0x12 is a control character — control-R — and 0x34 is the digit `4`.  And you probably get a couple of null bytes.  The control and null bytes don't display, so `4` is what you'd get from writing the UTF-32 value as shown — if your terminal is not set up to display UTF-32 (which it probably isn't).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   I'm surprised because I feel like the print function, I can actually display this unicode

Comment: OK; then use the print function that works — probably because it does the translation for you.  I'll play with your code when you add the missing bits (it shouldn't be many extra lines — maybe a dozen or so).  But I'm not ready to take code that can't be compiled to an executable and try to work out what you're doing in the missing bits — especially not with that `va_list *` argument.

Comment: You should compare the bytes output by the working `printf()` function with what your code outputs.  I'm fairly confident you'll find that `printf()` generates 3 bytes (0xE1 0x88 0xB4), and your code generates bytes 4 bytes (0x34 0x12 0x00 0x00, unless you're on a big-endian machine, in which case the bytes will be 0x00 0x00 0x12 0x34).  You could pipe the output of your program to `xxd -g 1` to get the bytes captured more or less appropriately.

Comment: That's exactly the case, I get "0x34 0x12 0x00 0x00", thank you. It escapes me a bit, how to play with the bits as you say. I will try to document myself @JonathanLeffler

Comment: you could use `wprintf()` and the rest of those 'wide' functions to handle the wide characters

Comment: it may be necessary to use a `setlocale()` statement

Comment: Would you like me to convert parts of my comments into some sort of answer, or would you prefer just to delete the question, @7hsk?